# Part of a loop in Visual Basic wont execute

Tags: vb.net

I am using a check digit at the 7th character.  Program runs with valid input.  When I intentionally use wrong check digit, my if statement does not execute??  Can't figure out why my if wont execute when the subsequent else is functioning.

```
 Private Sub btnEnter_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnter.Click
    Dim Sel As Integer, test As Boolean = False
    Dim PointerA As Integer
    txtResult.Clear()
    While test <> True And Sel < StudentNameArray.Length
        If radName.Checked = True Then
            If txtInput.Text = StudentNameArray(Sel) Then
                PointerA = StudentNameArray.Length
                txtResult.Text = "The ID is: " & StudentIDArray(Sel)
                test = True
            End If
        End If


        If radID.Checked = True Then
            If txtInput.Text = StudentIDArray(Sel) Then
                Dim idNum As Integer
                Dim pos1 As Integer
                Dim pos2 As Integer
                Dim pos3 As Integer
                Dim pos4 As Integer
                Dim pos5 As Integer
                Dim pos6 As Integer
                Dim pos7 As Integer
                Dim subTot As Integer = 0
                Dim m1 As Integer
                idNum = txtInput.Text
                pos1 = (Mid(idNum, 1, 1))
                pos2 = (Mid(idNum, 2, 1))
                pos3 = (Mid(idNum, 3, 1))
                pos4 = (Mid(idNum, 4, 1))
                pos5 = (Mid(idNum, 5, 1))
                pos6 = (Mid(idNum, 6, 1))
                pos6 = pos6 * 2
                pos5 = pos5 * 3
                pos4 = pos4 * 4
                pos3 = pos3 * 5
                pos2 = pos2 * 6
                pos1 = pos1 * 7
                subTot = (pos1 + pos2 + pos3 + pos4 + pos5 + pos5)
                m1 = subTot Mod 11
                m1 = 11 - m1
                pos7 = (Mid(idNum, 7, 1))
                If pos7 <> m1 Then
                    txtResult.Text = "Invalid ID, Select Clear or Exit"

                Else

                    PointerA = StudentIDArray.Length
                    txtResult.Text = "The Name is: " & StudentNameArray(Sel)
                    test = True
                End If

            End If
        End If

        Sel = Sel + 1

    End While
End Sub
```

Comment: I didn't look over all of it - just wanted to say that it really looks like you need to learn how to use arrays https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx

Comment: `subTot = (pos1 + pos2 + pos3 + pos4 + pos5 + pos5)` is wrong..

Comment: I'm just starting out in programming, haven't completed first semester yet.  I really need to learn lots of things...thanks

Comment: Please add `Option Strict On` to the top of your ".vb" file. It'll instantly make you a better programmer (once you fix all of the instant new errors.)

Comment: This line makes no sense:  `pos7 = (Mid(idNum, 7, 1))`  You are using Mid to get the 7th character as a string but are assigning it to an _Integer_ variable?  Do as Enigmativity said and put `Option Strict On` at the top of your VB file or set it in your project's properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're not getting the check sum computation right.

Firstly, the following line:

```
subTot = (pos1 + pos2 + pos3 + pos4 + pos5 + pos5)
```

should be:

```
subTot = (pos1 + pos2 + pos3 + pos4 + pos5 + pos6)
```

Note that you had `pos5` twice and no `pos6`.

And, to compute the check sum using mod it should look like this to get a single digit from `0` to `9`:

```
m1 = subTot Mod 10
m1 = 9 - m1
```

Your existing code could produce a value from `1` to `11` and not `0` to `9`.

In any case, try this code to compute the value:

```
Dim computed = _
    txtInput.Text _
        .ToCharArray() _
        .Select(Function(c, n) (txtInput.Text.Length - n) * (c - "0"c)) _
        .ToArray()

Dim m1 = 9 - (computed.Take(txtInput.Text.Length - 1).Sum() Mod 10)

Dim pos7 = computed.Last()
```

This code has the added advantage that it will work with any input number.